# How to run Bundle after installing?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, installation, bundle

I have done

```
gem install bundle
```

inside my directory that I have a git repository. But now when I try to run it with

```
bundle 
run bundle
bundle install
```

it says:

> Could not locate Gemfile.

How would I check that it has installed ?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it installed the gem correctly, however, you need to create a file named `Gemfile` for bundler to know what gems it should install. This file should be in your project's root. You can create one manually, or run `bundle init` to have a default one generated.

You can read more about the [Gemfile](http://bundler.io/gemfile.html) in the [docs](http://bundler.io/gemfile.html)